# How to download and extract apache tomcat using ansible and rename unzaip file

Tags: ansible

I’m setting up a new setup for tomcat.

I wanna download and extract apache tomcat using ansible to several nodes of linux, but the thing is unzip file should be seen or rename as apache only. It doesn't matter what would be a version of tomcat?

```
- name: variable check
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    tomcat_url: 'http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.45/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.45.tar.gz'
  tasks:
  - name:
    get_url:
      url: "{{tomcat_url}}"
      dest: /opt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's complete working example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    tomcat_url: 'http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.45/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.45.tar.gz'

  tasks:
    - name: Download and Extract apache tomcat
      unarchive:
        src: "{{ tomcat_url }}"
        dest: "/opt/"
        remote_src: yes

    - name: Synchronize the "{{ tomcat_url.split('/')[-1].rstrip('.tar.gz') }}" directory to apache on one remote host
      synchronize:
        src: "/opt/{{ tomcat_url.split('/')[-1].rstrip('.tar.gz') }}"
        dest: "/opt/apache"
      delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

    - name: Remove the {{ tomcat_url.split('/')[-1].rstrip('.tar.gz') }} directory
      file:
        path: "/opt/{{ tomcat_url.split('/')[-1].rstrip('.tar.gz') }}"
        state: absent
```